# Status 403 Forbidden Error : Microsoft graphs API https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have to generate an online meeting request from our Dynamics CRM System. We tried using the Microsoft graphs API, and were able to generate the token. However while submitting the request, we get a 403 Forbidden Error.  We have registered our application in Azure and also given the required API permissions.

I have attached the screenshots of our testing. I am testing this on my personal Azure test account.

Screenshots

[image: Testing screenshots]

Comment: Can you check on jwt.ms or on jwt.io if your token contains the correct permissions / scopes (check for the "scp" value)

Comment: Can you give more information about your graph request to get a token ? Copy paste the raw value of the request (from postman) replacing secrets by ****.

Answer (score 0):

The user has to consent the permission:
[Consent experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?source=docs#consent-experience)

```
Azure AD will sign the user in and ensure their consent for the permissions your app requests.

At this point, the user will be asked to enter their credentials to authenticate with Microsoft. The Microsoft identity platform v2.0 endpoint will also ensure that the user has consented to the permissions indicated in the scope query parameter. If the user has not consented to any of those permissions and if an administrator has not previously consented on behalf of all users in the organization, they will be asked to consent to the required permissions.
```